# How to print the unpredicted fields - awk

Tags: awk

I am trying to parse the input below by awk.
In case there are only 3 pair items meaning that if there are ID=34, ID2=35, COL3="231, the output looks good. As I just used 4 string variables in printf.
However, the number of items(ID/ID2/COL3) varies. That's the issue.

How can I print all these items even though the number of the items are not fixed?

Input

```
!{ID=34, ID2=35, COL3="231"}
>
!{ID=99, ID2=23}
>
!{ID=18, ID2=87}
<
@{ID=11, ID2=22, COL3="231",COL4="098", COL5="AAA", COL6="BBB"}
UPD1
```

Awk

```
BEGIN { FS="[}{[:space:] ]+"; RS="!|@" }
NR > 1 { 
printf "%s%s%s#%s\n", $2, $3, $4, $5;
}
```

Output

```
ID=34,ID2=35,COL3="231"#>
ID=99,ID2=23>#
ID=18,ID2=87<#
ID=11,ID2=22,COL3="231",COL4="098",#COL5="AAA",
```

Desired Output

```
ID=34,ID2=35,COL3="231"#>
ID=99,ID2=23#>
ID=18,ID2=87#<
ID=11,ID2=22,COL3="231",COL4="098",COL5="AAA",COL6="BBB"#UPD1
```

2nd Desired Output

```
!#ID=34,ID2=35,COL3="231"#>
!#ID=99,ID2=23#>
!#ID=18,ID2=87#<
@#ID=11,ID2=22,COL3="231",COL4="098",COL5="AAA",COL6="BBB"#UPD1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wonder if you are maybe getting hung up on working out fields, field separators and numbers of fields, when it may be possible to see the problem differently...

What if you forget fields and numbers of fields, and say *"if the line contains curly braces, remove all spaces, braces, at-signs and save the line, else print the saved line with a hash-sign and the current line"*?

```
awk '/{/ {gsub(/[ {}!@]/,"");m=$0;next} {print m"#"$0}' file

ID=34,ID2=35,COL3="231"#>
ID=99,ID2=23#>
ID=18,ID2=87#<
ID=11,ID2=22,COL3="231",COL4="098",COL5="AAA",COL6="BBB"#UPD1
```

Comment: Thanks. Can you show me how to do that with awk script?

Comment: Just put all the `awk` commands minus the single quotes in a file like you already did yourself.

Comment: Ok. Very simple solution. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

That is a very weird format.  I had to (re)install GNU Awk (4.1.3) to get the output you saw.  The BSD (Mac OS X) `awk` does not recognize the `@` in the multi-character `RS` value — see the notes below.

AFAICT, this code produces the output you seek with GNU Awk. It prefixes the last non-blank field on the line with a `#` mark.  Setting the `OFS` to an empty string outputs the fields with no space in between fields.

#### `script.awk`

```
BEGIN   { FS="[}{[:space:]]+"; RS="!|@"; OFS="" }
NR > 1  {
    # printf "%s%s%s#%s\n", $2, $3, $4, $5;
    for (i = NF; i > 1; i--)
    {
        if ($i != "")
        {
            $i = "#" $i
            break
        }
    }
    print
}
```

Example run:

```
$ gawk -f script.awk data
ID=34,ID2=35,COL3="231"#>
ID=99,ID2=23#>
ID=18,ID2=87#<
ID=11,ID2=22,COL3="231",COL4="098",COL5="AAA",COL6="BBB"#UPD1
$
```

For the same data file, BSD Awk generates:

```
$ awk -f script.awk data
ID=34,ID2=35,COL3="231"#>
ID=99,ID2=23#>
ID=18,ID2=87<@ID=11,ID2=22,COL3="231",COL4="098",COL5="AAA",COL6="BBB"#UPD1
$
```

It ignores the `@` in the `RS` value (and the `|` too, but the data doesn't demonstrate that).  However, this is legitimate according to the POSIX specification for [`awk`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html).

> **RS**
>
> The first character of the string value of RS shall be the input record separator; a `<newline>` by default. If RS contains more than one character, the results are unspecified. If RS is null, then records are separated by sequences consisting of a `<newline>` plus one or more blank lines, leading or trailing blank lines shall not result in empty records at the beginning or end of the input, and a `<newline>` shall always be a field separator, no matter what the value of FS is.

The GNU Awk extension is a valid unspecified behaviour; the BSD Awk behaviour of ignoring the extra characters is also a valid unspecified behaviour.

Comment: Great!. Can we also print RS(! or @) at the same time like 2nd Desired Output?

Comment: Thanks for your time.